# Design for class which accepts large array in constructor

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns

Let's say we have the following class which performs interpolation on irregularly spaced data:

```
template<class Real>
class interpolator
{
public:
    interpolator(const Real* const x, const Real* const y, size_t length)
    {
        m_x.resize(length);
        m_y.resize(length);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
             m_x[i] = x[i];
             m_y[i] = y[i];
        }
    }

    Real interpolate_at(Real x)
    {
        // use m_x and m_y to produce an estimate of y(x):
        return something;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Real> m_x;
    std::vector<Real> m_y;
};
```

This design has a number of things going for it: For one it is easy to use:

```
std::vector<double> x;
std::vector<double> y;
// Initialize x and y ...
interpolator<double> interp(x.data(), y.data(), y.size());
```

Since the constructor accepts primitive types, it can also be wrapped in Python with moderate effort (you'd need a shared object and some template instantiations, but let's assume that can be done). You can also let `x` and `y` go out of scope and the interpolator will still work.

The tragic flaw is that it performs a huge memcpy, which is slow and not space efficient.

Is there a way to refactor this class such that

- It is easy to wrap in Python (`std::shared_ptr`'s in interfaces are a nightmare to wrap . . .)
- It doesn't perform a memcpy
- The input data can be allowed to go out of scope and the interpolator still work

Comment: I don't think this can really be reviewed as it is now. For example, your `interpolate_at` is purely a stub that won't even compile (much less actually accomplish anything).

Comment: As a rule, "Let's say we have…" questions are too hypothetical to review.

Comment: Uhm. I've read that too late. I found this example already lacking enough.

Comment: `The input data can be allowed to go out of scope and the interpolator still work` you can't really escape this without copying the data. If copying is too expensive, keep the input in scope long enough to safely perform any calculation.

Comment: @D.Jurcau Technically, this does not mean, that the data is not allowed to be moved to `interpolator`.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't pass arrays as pointers ...**

... for multiple reasons. Your current design

1. always copies the arrays `x`, `y` deeply
2. can be misused by passing `nullptr` and trusts the user that `length` is chosen correctly.

Instead of

```
interpolator(const Real* const x, const Real* const y, size_t length) {  /* ... */ }
```

use

```
interpolator(std::vector<Real> x, std::vector<Real> y)
: m_x{std::move(x)}
, m_y{std::move(y)}
{ if (m_x.size() != m_y.size()) throw std::logic_error{"NO!"}; }
```

or if the memory layout doesn't effect the performance too much

```
interpolate(std::vector<std::array<Real, 2>> xy): m_xy{std::move(xy)} {}
```

If you want to initialise your data from any range use templates and constrain its type to guard for errors at compile time.

**Prefer regular functions for computations**

This means, that an implemented function is also a function in the mathematical sense. Same input data produces same output data. I found that this almost always leads to evaluations which do not change an inner state. Thus it smells to me that

```
Real interpolate_at(Real);
```

is not

```
Real interpolate_at(Real) const;
```